# Automating web page login with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script, login, web

I have been looking to write a bash script to automate login on an internal company website that is used as a Ping Board to monitor a network of IP connected cameras. I am pretty new to bash scripting and have no idea how to proceed. I have a command in the `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file that runs on boot and opens the Chromium browser full screen and directs to the page I require. I wish for the system to then automatically log in when at this page without requiring to save the password. I've had a look at the web page code and it is fairly straight forward, standard "Username" and "password" fields on the form. I'm a novice at coding in general but know I am looking for something that essentially identifies the relevant empty fields and populates them according to values I define as "Username" and "password" in the script. Any help would be appreciated and if I am missing any vital info on the issue please let me know. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

**[UPDATE]**

Since originally posting this issue I have found somewhat of a workaround. I use the old `http://User:Pass@domain.com` trick and this seems to log me in automatically, the only issue is that there is no HTML style sheet which is an issue as the IP Cameras are colour coded for up/down state and when in need of repairs etc. Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Bash isn't going to interact with the webpage for you. You need the browser to do it for you. You might want to look into browser plugins which can automate this kind of behaviour. Selenium might not be the best choice, but it can get the job done for you.

Comment: Best way is by using  a "user script". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome).

Comment: @xenoid I appreciate the link but as I say I am a novice to programming, the contents of that post confuse me more than inform me, I managed to find a little workaround by doing the 'http://user:pass@domain.com' trick but then I am left with a blank style sheet which is problematic as the cameras are colour coded for up/down state. Thanks for the reply nonetheless.

Comment: @mtak I know that bash will not interact with the web page, all I want it to do is launch with predefined parameters, almost like an injection, the script I am using is simply one command; "chromium-browser --start-fullscreen Required_URL" which works fine.